# pygame.error: No available video device? what is wrong? replit error

Tags: python, pygame, replit

I was working in python and I just started with pygame and I am using a tutorial but it says"Traceback (most recent call last): file "main.py", line 5 in  win=pygame.display.set_mode((500,500)) pygame.error: No available video device"
can someone please explain what this error is telling me because after countless internet searches I still found nothing that helped. here is my code.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Client")

clientnumber = 0

win.fill((255, 255, 255))

class player():
  def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, color):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.color = color
    self.rect = (x, y, width, height)
    self.vel = 3

  def draw(self, win):
    pygame.draw.rect(win, self.color, self.rect)

  def move(self):
     key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

     if key[pygame.K_LEFT]: 
       self.x -= self.vel

     if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
       self.x += self.vel

     if key[pygame.K_UP]:
       self.y -= self.vel

     if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
       self.y += self.vel

     self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)

def redrawWindow(win, player):
  win.fill((255, 255, 255))
  player.draw(win)
  pygame.display.update()


def main():
  run = True
  p = player(50, 50, 100, 100, (0,255,0))
  clock = pygame.time.Clock()

  while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
        pygame.quit()

    p.move()
    redrawWindow(win, p)

main()
```

Comment: do you run it on `replit`? PyGame needs video card and monitor connected to computer on which you run it - and if you run it on `replit` then you run it on server which doesn't have video card and monitor. I'm not sure but `replit` may need special version of `PyGame`

Answer (score 0):

`PyGame` needs access to video card and graphics mode (and monitor) on computer on which it runs code. If you run it on `replit` then it runs code on server which usually doesn't run in graphics mode but in text mode.

You have to select template `PyGame` to run special version which can run `PyGame`.

[image]

Comment: Facing this issue even on a Pygame template. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75942620/replit-pygame-error-no-available-video-device-even-on-a-pygame-template